# ASP.NET Core change AccessDenied route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-identity-3

I'm having some trouble with routing AccessDenied, probably Login/Logout path as well. The project is a stripped default one with no more magic. Soo there exist a `Account` controller with an `AccessDenied()` method.

What I'm trying now is (this is the solution offered by the goods of the internet)

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/InactiveSponsor");
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/");
});
```

But that does absolutely no difference. So any ideas? Any idea on why don't it work and how to make it work.

Here is my Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
        builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
    }
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    string connection = "DefaultConnection";
    //services.AddDbContext<SponsorContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddDbContext<SponsorContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration[$"Data:{connection}"]));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SponsorContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


    services.AddMvc();


    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(Policies.RequireAdmin, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Administrator));
        options.AddPolicy(Policies.IsSponsor, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Sponsor));
        options.AddPolicy(Policies.IsSponsorOrAdmin, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Administrator, Roles.Sponsor));
    });

    /*
     * AddTransient Different on each instance/use
     * AddScoped Different instance on a per request basis
     * AddSingleton Always the same instance
     */
    //DI
    services.AddScoped<ManageUserRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ISponsorManagement, SponsorRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ISponsorRead, SponsorRepository>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseIdentity();


    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you post `Configure` method code? Probably you override `CookieAuthenticationOptions`.

Comment: @ademcaglin added the whole startup

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(op=>op.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/InactiveSponsor"))
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SponsorContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Or

```
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/aa");
            opt.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/InactiveSponsor");
            opt.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = new PathString("/");
        });
```

Comment: has anyone got this solution to work with IdentityServer4?

Answer (score 19):

For similar problems into an ASP.NET Core 2.x web app, if the authentication is made with Azure AD /OpenID Connect, you can change the route in this way.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>...)
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>...)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/path/unauthorized";
                options.LoginPath = "/path/login";
            });
```

Answer (score 14):

In case someone experiences similar problems in ASP.NET Core 2, you could replace `services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(...)` with `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie()` like this:

Replace this in your Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/[your-path]");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/[your-path]");
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/[your-path]");
});
```

with this:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/[your-path]");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/[your-path]");
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/[your-path]");
});
```

Comment: `ConfigureApplicationCookie` is part of ASP.NET Identity, if you're not using ASP.NET Identity (such as me, I'm using IdentityServer4 without ASP.NET Identity) then neither of these approaches work.